# Stripe.create functions not in correct order

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I want to integrate Stripe into my application. I have collected all necessary Data in the req.body. 
Now an undefined error is being thrown after creating the customer Id and while trying to pass it to addCustomerToCard. After that, createToken is being successfully logged.

So two questions:
1.Why is the order of functions not being invoked as I would expect?
2.Why does the customer not get passed in addCustomerToCard?

```
router.post("/checkout", async function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.cart) {
    return res.redirect("/shopping-cart");
  }
  let createCustomer = function () {
    var param ={};
    param.email = req.body.email;
    param.name= req.body.name;
    param.description ="";
    return stripe.customers.create(param, function (err, customer) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err:" + err);
      }
      if (customer) {
        console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(customer, null, 2));
      } else {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      }
    });


  };

  let createToken = function () {
    let param ={};
    param.card = {
      number: req.body.card,
      exp_month: req.body.exp_month,
      exp_year: req.body.exp_year,
      cvc: req.body.security
  }
    return stripe.tokens.create(param, function (err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err:" + err);
        console.log(param);
      }
      if (token) {
        console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(token, null, 2));
        console.log(req.body);
      } else {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      }
    });
  };




  let addCardToCustomer = function () {
    console.log(createdCustomer);
   return stripe.customers.createSource(customer.id, {source: token.id}, function (err, card) {
     if (err) {
       console.log("err:" + err);
       console.log(param);
     }
     if (card) {
       console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(card, null, 2));
     } else {
       console.log("something went wrong");
     }
   });
 };

 let chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID = function () {
   let param = {
     amount: cart.totalPrice,
     currency: 'eur',
     description: 'First payment',
     customer: customer.id
   }

   stripe.charges.create(param, function (err, charge) {
     if (err) {
       console.log("err: " + err);
     }
     if (charge) {
       console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(charge, null, 2));
     } else {
       console.log("Something wrong")
     }
   })
 }


  try {
    const createdCustomer = await createCustomer(); // promise 1
    const createdToken = await createToken();
    const addedCardToCustomer = await addCardToCustomer(createdCustomer,createdToken ); // 
    // const chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID = await chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID(); // promise 4


    res.send("success");

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`error ${e}`)
  };



});

//LOG OUTPUT


//success
//error ReferenceError: createdCustomer is not defined
//success
```

Answer (score 0):

You should break this down into smaller pieces to verify the behaviour you're expecting, for starters. There's quite a lot going on here.

One problem is that you are trying to `await` functions which are not `async` -- you should have each function marked:

```
let createCustomer = async function () {...}
```

This is likely the reason the sequence is not what you expect.

You're hitting an error in `addCardToCustomer` because `createCustomer` is `undefined` in the [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) of that function. You need to have a parameter:

```
let addCardToCustomer = async function (createdCustomer) { ... }
```