# Error when trying to pass value in async function (Stripe charging process)

Tags: javascript, async-await, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stipe into my project. In order to create a charge i need to create some values and pass it on to the next function. I currently have a async function chain in order to do so, but for some reason one of the values (created token) is not being passed on (error: undefined).
I tried it with passing the returned value of the function as well as saving the needed value in a object and then passing on the object.
Both customer and token are being correctly generated, but only the customer is being passed on to the addCardToCustomer function.
Can anyone spot a mistake a made here?

```
router.post("/checkout", async function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.cart) {
    return res.redirect("/shopping-cart");
  }

  let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
  let customerId = {};

  let createCustomer = async function () {
    var param = {};
    param.email = req.body.email;
    param.name = req.body.name;
    param.description = "";
    return stripe.customers.create(param, function (err, customer) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err:" + err);
      }
      if (customer) {
        console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(customer, null, 2));
        customerId.id = customer.id;
      } else {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      }
    });
//CUSTOMER CREATED

  };

  let createToken = async function () {
    let param = {};

    param.card = {
      number: req.body.card,
      exp_month: req.body.exp_month,
      exp_year: req.body.exp_year,
      cvc: req.body.security
    }
    return stripe.tokens.create(param, function (err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err:" + err);

      }
      if (token) {
        console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(token, null, 2));
        console.log(req.body);
        customerId.t_Id = token.id;
        console.log(customerId.t_Id)
      } else {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      }
    });
  };

//TOKEN CREATED


  let addCardToCustomer = async function (createdToken) {

    return stripe.customers.createSource(customerId.id, {
      source: createdToken
    }, function (err, card) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err:" + err);
        console.log(customerId.id)
        //CUSTOMER IS DEFINED
        console.log(customerId.t_id);
        //TOKEN UNDEFINED
      }
      if (card) {
        console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(card, null, 2));
      } else {
        console.log("something went wrong");
      }
    });
  };

  //CUSTOMER.ID WORKS; TOKEN ID NOT

  let chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID = async function () {
    let param = {
      amount: cart.totalPrice * 100,
      currency: 'eur',
      description: 'First payment',
      customer: customerId.id
    }

   return stripe.charges.create(param, function (err, charge) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err: " + err);
      }
      if (charge) {
        console.log("success: " + JSON.stringify(charge, null, 2));
      } else {
        console.log("Something wrong")
      }
    })
  }


  try {
    const createdCustomer = await createCustomer(); 
    const createdToken = await createToken();
    const addedCardToCustomer = await addCardToCustomer(createdToken); 
    const chargedCustomerThroughCustomerID = await chargeCustomerThroughCustomerID(); 


    res.send("success");

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`error ${e}`)
  };



});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stripe.create functions not in correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661578/stripe-create-functions-not-in-correct-order)

Comment: Excuse me, for some reasen i posted my old version of the code. I edited it as you said, but the error is still the same. Did I do as you said or am I missing again something.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered you on this question: your function are missing `async` and arguments.

See answer here: [Stripe.create functions not in correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661578/stripe-create-functions-not-in-correct-order/60661853#60661853)

Comment: Excuse me, for some reasen i posted my old version of the code. I edited it as you said, but the error is still the same. Did I do as you said or am I missing again something. – misah 9 mins ago